# How to create an instance to call a method of an activity to a service class in Android?

Tags: java, android

In my Android project, I have a service class, from where I pass value to one static method of a fragment.

Here's the code of my **service class**-

```
    public class MyLocationService extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public static final String ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATE = "my package name";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            if(intent != null) {
                final String action = intent.getAction();
                if(ACTION_PROCESS_UPDATE.equals(action)) {
                    LocationResult result = LocationResult.extractResult(intent);

                    if(result != null) {
                        Location location = result.getLastLocation();
                        String location_string = new StringBuilder(""+location.getLatitude())
                                                        .append("/")
                                                        .append(location.getLongitude())
                                                        .toString();

                        try {
                            HomeFragment.getInstance().updateLocationText(""+location.getLatitude(), ""+location.getLongitude());

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, location_string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.e("##Error:", e+"");
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

        } 
}
```

In my **HomeFragment** class, I have initialized the instance like below-

```
static HomeFragment instance;
    public static HomeFragment getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
```

And then use the method for service class like below-

```
 public void updateLocationText(final String latitude, final String longitude) {

        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.e("#MY_LOCATION:", latitude+"/ "+longitude);
                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
                databaseReference.child(userEmail).child("latitude").setValue(latitude);
                databaseReference.child(userEmail).child("longitude").setValue(longitude);


            }
        });

    }
```

These code works perfectly like the way I have done in fragment class.

**Now, the problem is -
----------------------------**

I want to do the same work in my Activity class. For that purpose, I have created the instance like below-

```
 static AllUsersActivity instance;

    public static AllUsersActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
```

And then in the service class I have called the method like below-

```
try {
AllUsersActivity.getInstance().updateLocationText3(""+location.getLatitude(), ""+location.getLongitude());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, location_string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("##Error:", e+"");
                    }
```

But here, using instance to call it in Activity class, it is getting null pointer exception.
I am not getting why is happening as the same sort of work is going well in fragment but what problem actually occurs while doing this in Activity.

So, it would be very nice if someone helps me to find the problem and solve it.

Comment: try eventbus `https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus`
from service received in activity or fragment

Answer (score 1):

This is a poor solution, you can't have your broadcast receiver depending on instances of your UI classes. If you need your UI to be notified of events happening in your receiver, you could use some Rx bus or similar solution where you push events onto the bus and then your UI would subscribe to said bus and react to the events.

Another option is to declare your Activity as singleInstance and then pass the payload to it via a start intent, which would be received in `onNewIntent` if the activity is already running.